# Basic C programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program which given a certain number of input will output the product of the listed input (only accounting inputs of 0-9 and ignoring other). For example: input:345 would result output: 60, or another example would be, input: 3t4 and output: 12

I have given it many attempts and this is what I'm stuck with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){

    int c,i;

    c = getchar();
    i = 1;
    while (c!= '\n'){
        if (c>=48 && c<=57){
          i=c*i;
          c=getchar();
        }
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    }
```

Comment: Your program will hang if the user enters an invalid digit, as you never give the user the opportunity to enter a new char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
i = c*i;
```

to

```
i = (c - '0')*i;
```

What is happening here is the variable `c` contains the ascii value of the number not the number. So, `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49 and so forth. So when you enter 12, you will not get `1x2` but `49x50`.

Take a look at the ascii chart. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: There's more wrong with the code than just the failure to convert the characters to their corresponding integers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the curly braces from inner if block

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int c,i;

    c = getchar();
    i = 1;
    while (c!= '\n'){
        if (c>=48 && c<=57)              
        i = (c-'0')*i;
        c=getchar(); 
    }
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the characters that you have read into their corresponding numeric values. Since you are only using single digits, you can exploit/abuse the fact that the ASCII characters for '0' to '9' are in order (from 48 to 57).

Using a `do { } while()`, rather than `while() { }` obviates the need to “preset” `c` outside the loop.

The correct header for `main` is either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, and you should `return` a value from `main`.

The following should work, although I admit that I haven't compiled or tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;     /* Character read */
    int i = 1; /* Product */

    do {
        c = getchar();
        if (c>='0' && c<='9'){
            i *= (c-'0');
        }
    } while( c != '\n' );

    printf("Product: %d\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things to be taken care of :
(1). Remove curly braces of if block.
(2). Take care of conversion from ascii code to number.
   i = (c - '0') * i;