# Basic C programming

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program which given a certain number of input will output the product of the listed input (only accounting inputs of 0-9 and ignoring other).

For example:

```
input:345 would result output: 60, or another example would be, input: 3t4 and output: 12
```

I have given it many attempts and this is what I'm stuck with :

```
#include <stdio.h>


main(){

int c,i;

c = getchar();
i = 1;
while (c!= '\n'){
        if (c>=48 && c<=57){
          i=c*i;
          c=getchar();
        }
}
printf("%d",i);
}
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: What are your problems?

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply by `c-'0'`?

Comment: For starts stop using the magic numbers `48` and `57`. Replace them with `'0'` and `'9'` respectively. And add in a `c != EOF` check to your `while` condition.

Comment: Either use standard lib function `isdigit` or at least if( (c>='0') && (c<='9')). Avoid any magic numbers in your code to make it more readable

Comment: I doubt a beginner would even know what a magic number is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907120/basic-c-programming)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues in your code.

- After each time the program encounters a non-numeric character it doesn't read further from the input. It reads the same character. Hence `c=getchar()` should be outside the `if` block
- The multiplication happens for the `char` variable `c`. It should be converted to the actual number and then be multiplied. In your code you are multiplying its ascii value. Hence `(c-48)*i` instead of `c*i`

Answer (score 0):

Use  `i=(c-48)*i;` instead of `i = c*i`. So, the changed program would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

int c,i;

c = getchar();
i = 1;
while (c!= '$'){
//    printf("%c\n", c);
        if (c>=48 && c<=57){
          i=(c-48)*i;
        }
        c=getchar();
}
printf("%d",i);
}
```

This will ensure that you are using the numeric value of the digit, `0` not as ascii code of `0` but as simple `0`.
use `c=getchar()` outside the if block. This should work.

Comment: Try out the code. It won't work. It accepts one number and prints it.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, edited with the correction, check it now

Comment: @Rikayan Bandyopadhyay: The OP has all input on a single line; I assume he _wants_ to exit on newline. Seems elegant to me, for a one-shot prog.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, oops, you are using multi-line input, then you cannot use while (c!= '\n'), you have to use some other character instead e.g. while (c!= '$'){... where $ is the end of input marker, for example. However based, on your original example, the newline character checking will work, your original example was to have a single line input, input:345 would result output: 60, or another example would be, input: 3t4 and output: 12

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, well if you accept, you can always upvote and accept the edited answer if u like

Comment: Okay, here's a +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,c;

i = 1;

while (i){

    c=getchar();

    if(c == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }

    if (c < 48 || c > 57)
    {
        i = -1;
        break;
    }

    i = i * (c-48);

}

if (i == -1)
{
    printf("Error. Non-Number Entered\n\n");
}

else {

    printf("%d\n\n",i);

}
```